# List of process along with its child

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, data-structures, stl

In one of my component, I need to maintain all processes in some data structure which will be populated on process creation and termination. This data structure has to be super fast in terms of lookup. This data structure would be queried to fetch a list of child processes of any process id. I am not sure what could be the data structure I should use here.

{ParentProcessId } - { List of child Process Ids}

This list would be populated every time a process gets created/terminated so as to update data structure.

Comment: Instead of *super fast lookup* you are really looking for *atomicity*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create a similar data structure in one of my projects. I found that `std::map` along with `std::unordered_set` is the best container to have these info stored.

`map<parentID, unordered_set<ChildIDs>> PCMap;`

Note: I used a set instead of a list as I do not want to have more than one similar child IDs in my list.

Comment: Map is certainly faster. But the problem comes when a process exists and I want to remove its entry from its parent's ChildIds list. In this case, I will have iterate through map, get childids of each element, lookup in the set and remove if found. I want a faster solution here by using data structure.

Comment: You have methods like `map::at` and `unordered_set::find` which are logarithmic in complexity. So, this indeed is a faster solution. Probably you can also use multithreading(Just filling the map) to improve the performance.